# getCurrentPosition / watchPosition in Chrome (65.0.3325.162)

Tags: html, google-chrome, geolocation

Do you have tried to use getCurrentPosition or watchPosition in Chrome (65.0.3325.162 version) from Desktop?
Before this version it worked perfectly. Now at first loading it works, after it's very slow and in more case it does not work.
Why does this happen? You can try it on any demo, for example https://html5demos.com/geo/

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a result of the change in Chrome described in https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=820945#c8

Adding appropriate `timeout` and/or `maximumAge` options to the `PositionOptions` object passed to `getcurrentPosition` et al should fix it.